# Edit function using modal dialog (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in my application/view/userlist.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.edit-row').live('click',function(){
            var me = $(this);
            var editModal = $('#myModalEdit');
            editModal.find('#userFullName').val(me.attr('data-userFullName'));
            editModal.find('#userID').val(me.attr('data-userID'));
            editModal.find('#userName').val(me.attr('data-userName'));
            editModal.find('#userPass').val(me.attr('data-userPass'));
            editModal.find('#userEmail').val(me.attr('data-userEmail'));
            $('#myModalEdit').modal('show');
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit System User <label id="userFullName"></label></h4>
            </div>

        <form role="form" id="userForm" action="<?php echo base_url().'admin/updateUser'; ?>" method= "POST">

        <!-- #myModalEdit codes here-->

        </form>

<!-- some html codes -->

    <a class="edit-row" href="javascript:" 
        data-userID="<?php echo $row->userID; ?>"
        data-userFullName="<?php echo $row->userFullName; ?>"
        data-userName="<?php echo $row->userName; ?>"
        data-userEmail="<?php echo $row->userEmail; ?>"
        data-userPass="<?php echo $row->userPass; ?>"                                           
    >                                   
    <button type="button" data-hover="tooltip" title="Edit User <?php echo $row->userName; ?>" class="btn btn-default">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    </button>
    </a>
```

I got error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

What does it mean?

Comment: Which version of jquery you are using? Latest versions will not support `.live`. Use `.on` instead

Comment: have you included jquery link in your code.Remember live function is now absolute and no longer included in latest jquery version .

Comment: i'm using jQuery 1.10

Comment: i've changed to .on but i get error on .modal(show) now..  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function. Already include bootstrap too..

Comment: SOLVED.. I accidentally include jQuery twice.. >.< thanks guys... BTW.. it works with .on instead .live Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `.on()` instead of `.live()`

try

```
$(parentDiv).live('click', '.edit-row', function(){ 
  // write you code here
});
```

Comment: Thank you .. SOLVED.. i changed to .on